# Debian jessie fails to boot - changed the fstab file

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, ssd, mount

All,

I have recently installed Debian Linux on my machine. It's working great. However it wasnt showing my two 2TB hard drives. It was only showing the my main 256GB SSD onto which the OS was installed. I am not that familiar with Linux mounting etc. So did some googling and added two lines to the /etc/fstab file which I thought would let the OS recognize my two 2TB(not external) hard drives.

But after I made those changes and tried to reboot it would always fail. What are my options now? Please advise.

Thanks in Advance

**Update1**: So I downloaded Debian 8.2 Live and was able to get into my system. Now when I tried to change the fstab I get an error saying that I dont have write permissions. I could not figure out how to gain root access to my system from the Live CD. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Update2** I have also started posting on superuser.com but for all those who have answered and wanted more details, here they go:

1) Finally was able to delete the lines I added to the fstab file using Debian Live CD and now I am back into my system

2) sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT, LABEL 
NAME   FSTYPE            SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sdb                    238.5G
├─sdb1 ext4            228.8G /
├─sdb2                     1K
└─sdb5 swap              9.7G [SWAP]
sdc    ddf_raid_member   1.8T
sdd    ddf_raid_member   1.8T
sr0                     1024M

3) Contents of my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name   devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=1bbcf72f-eeba-45ad-a946-0d03606ff6c9 /               ext4         errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=a84f25cc-3bf2-4a73-b1ad-fba59b939374 none            swap    sw                 0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

My question is still why am I not able to access my two 2TB hard drives? I think they are named sdc and sdd as seen above in item 2) i put

Comment: Use `sudo` with Debian live systems. It will execute the command with superuser rights. Other than the regular user which has a password, `sudo` will not ask for a superuser password.

Comment: Can you show the fstab contents? 
With your live cd the existing disks are probably mounted read only. try: mount -o remount,rw <filesystem>

Comment: (Closed) cross-site duplicate, currently with some additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818695/debian-jessie-fails-to-boot-changed-the-fstab-file